# while deploying my react project on netlify showing error: Can't resolve '../../assets/CV.pdf' in '/opt/build/repo/src/components/header'

Tags: reactjs

Everything fine locally I am able to download pdf locally. But while deploying on my site, its showing error below;

```
11:42:11 PM: Creating an optimized production build...
11:42:13 PM: Failed to compile.
11:42:13 PM: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 
'../../assets/CV.pdf' in '/opt/build/repo/src/components/header'
11:42:13 PM:   "build.command" failed                                       
11:42:13 PM:   Error message
11:42:13 PM:   Command failed with exit code 1: npm run build (https://ntl.fyi/exit-code-1)
11:42:13 PM:   Error location
11:42:13 PM:   In Build command from Netlify app
```

You can take a look at my code [from here](https://github.com/gitAbishek/absihekportfolioupdated). It works locally but I can't deploy.

Comment: Is it going to the final build? can you be sure of that?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error above appears to be concluding 3rd line not to be compiled successfully;

```
11:42:13 PM: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../assets/CV.pdf' in '/opt/build/repo/src/components/header'
```

As per the repo you shared above, there's **`cv.pdf`** under `/src/assets/` but not **`CV.pdf`** like below and as it's stated within `/src/components/header/CTA.js`;

```
import CV from '../../assets/CV.pdf'
```

Like stated here at 4th paragraph within [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/JavaScript_basics#variables), Javascript is a case-sensitive language so that, **CV.pdf** and **cv.pdf** is totally different things like any other variable name represented in this context provides.

Comment: there's CV.pdf not cv.pdf under /src/assets

Comment: Thankyou so much for your response though in my project there's CV.pdf under /src/assets/  but after pushing it to github its showing cv.pdf, so I renamed it to cv.pdf insted of CV.pdf and it worked. no idea why it dosent support when it was saved with(CV.pdf) instead (cv.pdf)

Comment: Well, as you figure out with the example above, it’s important to keep the “path” and the “name” belong to that file/folder same in order to make it work. Other than this, you can choose a name of your preference for your files and variables even there are best practices and some restrictions. Eventually I’m glad that it worked.